# Github actions CMake: Error Cannot load cache

Tags: github, cmake, github-actions

I moved my `CMakeLists.txt` from the root into my `src/` directory and I reconfigured my CMake workflow. The error comes from the build scope. Error loading Cache.

**My Configuration:**

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Configure CMake
      run: cmake ${{github.workspace}}/src -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${{env.BUILD_TYPE}}

    - name: Build
      run: cmake --build  ${{github.workspace}}/src --config ${{env.BUILD_TYPE}}

    - name: Test
      working-directory: ${{github.workspace}}/src/build
      run: ctest -C ${{env.BUILD_TYPE}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the command `cmake ${{github.workspace}}/src -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${{env.BUILD_TYPE}}` you set the location of the CMakeLists.txt, the cmake output directory is still the current working directory `.`. This output directory should be passed to `--build`

```yaml
- name: Build
  run: cmake --build . --config ${{env.BUILD_TYPE}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear and concise answer!